# Why would a "No SLF4J" "No SLF4J providers were found" provider found error occur when SLF4J is in Maven pom.xml file?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, pom.xml, slf4j

I am currently getting the below errors when trying to run a Spring Java program.
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Here is the section in the pom.xml file that has the SLF4J and Log4J dependencies.

```
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0.9</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core -->
<dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
<version>1.4.14</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
<dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
<version>1.4.14</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If there are any thoughts on how to resolve this, I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: you only provided the provider on scope 'test', not the other ones

Comment: Check the manual https://slf4j.org/manual.html